# Two webapps sharing the same servlet code

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, web-applications, internationalization

Is the following thing possible:

- having a first webapp `fr`,
- having a second webapp `en`,
- having a Java project `P` which contains the servlets (the classes that extend `HttpServlet`) that the two webapps `fr` and `en` need,
- `web.xml` in `fr` references a servlet `S` in the Java project `P`,
- `web.xml` in `en` references the same servlet `S` as `fr` in the Java project `P`.

  ```
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>AServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.projp.AServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/a_servlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```

In the `servlet-class` XML element, I would need the tell the two webapps `fr` and `en` that the servlet `S` is in project `P` and not in projects `fr` or `en`.

Is it possible or do I need to duplicate the Java code for the servlets in both `fr` and `en` projects?

Comment: What have you already *tried*?

Comment: It looks like it is feasible using a webfragment.